# Second order statistical measures and phase information

Tags: autocorrelation, moments

I am reading this page :
http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/applied/news.dir/issue2/hos_intro.html

the author mentions that :
"Second-order measures (such as the power spectrum and autocorrelation functions) contain no phase information. As a consequence of this non-minimum phase signals cannot be correctly identified by 2nd-order techniques"

can some one explain to me please why the second order measures doesn't not have any phase information but higher order measure have?

Many thanks
Danial